# Relation between gradient norm and distance to optimizer

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

For context, this problem arose when I was trying to prove convergence rate bounds for convex optimization algorithms.

Let $f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathcal{X} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex. Moreover, let $f$ be a [$\mu$-strongly convex](https://xingyuzhou.org/blog/notes/strong-convexity), [$G$-Lipschitz continuous](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LipschitzFunction.html), with [$L$-Lipschitz continuous gradients](https://xingyuzhou.org/blog/notes/Lipschitz-gradient) (a.k.a. $L$-smooth). We can also assume that $\|x - y\|_2 \leq R$ for all $x,y \in \mathcal{X}$.

Define $x^* := \text{arg}\min_{x\in\mathcal{X}} f(x)$. My goal is to prove the following statement:

> $$
> \frac{1}{2L}\|\nabla f(x)\|^2_2 - \frac{\mu}{2}\|x - x^*\|^2_2 \leq 0, \quad \forall x \in \mathcal{X}. \tag{1}
> $$

So far, I was able to show that it holds for the special case when $L=\mu>0$, and $x^*$ belongs to the relative interior of $\mathcal{X}$ (i.e., $\nabla f(x^*) = 0$). To do so, I used the following argument:

> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{2L}\|\nabla f(x)\|^2_2 - \frac{\mu}{2}\|x - x^*\|^2_2 
> &\leq \frac{1}{2L}\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(x^*)\|^2_2 - \frac{\mu}{2}\|x - x^*\|^2_2 \\
> &\leq \frac{L}{2}\|x - x^*\|^2_2 - \frac{\mu}{2}\|x - x^*\|^2_2 \\
> &= 0.
> \end{align*}

**QUESTION:** is it possible to prove that $(1)$ holds for general $L,\mu$? If not, are there other special cases/assumptions under which the statement holds?

Comment: The answer is no, since if $\nabla f(x^*)\neq 0$ or if $\mu \neq L$, one can easily construct a counter example that shows the relation you're trying to prove does not hold. Your analysis is tight, which is a good thing, but it relies on strong assumptions. However the important question is why do you want to prove this relation? If it's for the purpose of convergence rate analysis I refer you to https://web.iem.technion.ac.il/images/user-files/becka/papers/gradient_chapter.pdf (section 1.4.2 and 1.4.3) for an excellent, easily readable technique